# Show that with probability one the events cease to occur ultimately under certain conditions

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of independent events with
$$lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n)=0.$$
Suppose that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n^c \cap A_{n+1}) < \infty.$$
Will the events $A_n$ cease to occur eventually with probability one?

I think that the question is asking to show that 
$$P(A_n\ i.o.)=0$$
And I tried to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)<\infty$$
So that I can use the Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

But I did not get nowhere. I am kind of confused about all these operations includes limits, sets, and interplays between them, as well as the $limsup$ and $liminf$ stuff. Hope someone could help me.

Comment: You can't conclude $\sum_nP(A_n)<\infty$ from these assumptions--e.g., take $A_n=[0,1/n]$ to be your events on the unit interval with lebesgue (uniform) measure.

Comment: @Math1000 This question isn't quite a duplicate. It assumes $\sum P(A_n^c \cap A_{n+1}) < \infty$, but the question cited assumes $\sum P(A_n \cap A_{n+1}^c) < \infty$. For example the counterexample I give in my comment is not a counterexample to the cited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to take advantage of the $\sum_n P(A_{k+1}\cap A_k^c)<\infty$ assumption, write$A_{n+2}\cap A_n^c=(A_{n+2}\cap A_{n+1}^c\cap A_n^c)\cup (A_{n+2}\cap A_{n+1}\cap A_n^c)\subset (A_{n+2}\cap A_{n+1}^c)\cup (A_{n+1}\cap A_n^c)$, and proceeding inductively, 
$$
A_{n+k}\cap A_n^c\subset \cup_{i=n}^{k-1}(A_{i+1}\cap A_i^c).
$$

Next, 
$$
\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_k=\cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_k\cap A_n)\cup (A_k\cap A_n^c)\subset A_n\cup \{\cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_{k+1}\cap A_k^c)\}.
$$

The last relation follows from the preceding display. We are given that $\sum_n P(A_{k+1}\cap A_k^c)<\infty$, which by borel-cantelli implies $P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_{k+1}\cap A_k^c))\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. We are also given $P(A_n)\to 0$. Therefore 
$$
P(\limsup A_n)=P(\cap_{n=0}^\infty\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty A_n)\le \lim_{n\to\infty} P(A_n)+P(\cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_{k+1}\cap A_k^c))=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is clear to me now!

Comment: Sorry I think I am still a bit confused about the relation that $\cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_k\cap A_n)\cup (A_k\cap A_n^c)\subset A_n\cup \{\cup_{k=n}^\infty (A_{k+1}\cap A_k^c)\}$. Could you elaborate more on it?

Comment: Decomposing the left hand side of that relation, you first have all the terms $A_k\cap A_n,k\ge n$, each of which is contained in $A_n$, which appears on the rhs. Next you have the terms $A_k\cap A_n^c,k\ge n$. From earlier in my answer you have that each of these is equal to $\cup_{i=n}^k (A_{i+1}\cap A_i^c),k\ge n$, which in turn is contained $\cup_{i=n}^\infty (A_{i+1}\cap A_i^c)$, which appears on the rhs also. So the entire lhs is contained in the rhs.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! It is very helpful!